# Play push notification sound ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic2

It is possible to play sound on Ionic in push notifications when the user device in the silent mode? I'm using ionic v.2.2.3, "phonegap-plugin-push", APNS for ios and GCM for android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the payload documentation https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/PAYLOAD.md#sound
, you're able to send a payload/notification such as:

**Android**

```
{
    "registration_ids": ["my device id"],
    "data": {
        "title": "Default",
        "message": "Plays default notification sound",
        "soundname": "default"
    }
}
```

**iOS**

```
{
    "aps": {
        "alert": "Test sound",
        "sound": "default"
    }
}
```

which will play the phones default notification sound.

Comment: The question was "It is possible to play sound on Ionic in push notifications when the user device in the silent mode?", not "How to add a custom sound to the ionic push notifications"

Comment: @Sklerozz Did you find a solution ?

Comment: Silent mode, we doin't think sound can be played.

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya What would be the solution to launch an alarm then ?
My goal is to launch an alarm on the user's phone even when it's on silent mode.

Comment: @qwertzuiop I would say that is aggressive solution, but I like it